# What's the point of near-warp transport?

Tags: star-trek

With warp drive, you jump out of warp and back into full speed very quickly, it doesn't take any measurable time to accelerate (300millseconds (last outpost). So, executing this dangerous procedure for an added 3 seconds seems overtly risky for the small amount of advantage it gives. **Why would anybody use near-warp transport, considering how risky it is, to gain a minimal 3 seconds?**

Comment: @N_Soong sure..

Comment: @N_Soong yes, and why would anybody choose to do it when it only gives 3 seconds, of which, would not make a difference on a mission of medical.

Comment: @TheDoc sorry, haven't logged on in months :)

Comment: no worries and thanks 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To save time in critical situations

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Near-warp_transport) explains that near-warp was used during TNG: *The Schizoid Man*:

> This procedure was used by the crew of the USS Enterprise-D in 2365
>   when transporting an away team down to Gravesworld to respond to a
>   distress call from that planet. **Due to a concurrent medical emergency**
>   on the USS Constantinople, Commander Riker suggested using near-warp
>   transport in order **to minimize the amount of time it would take the
>   Enterprise to reach the Constantinople**.

This emergency was a very pressing one:

> While en route, a distress call is picked up from the USS
>   Constantinople, which has suffered an **outer hull breach**, and is
>   carrying 2,012 colonists.

([Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Schizoid_Man_%28episode%29))

so any delays in responding to the emergency would be quite unacceptable.

Now, it's important to remember that **ordinarily, when entering a star system, a starship *leaves warp and goes to impulse***, the reasons for this are outlined in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79884/22917).  Now, impulse is considerably slower than warp drive - [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54837/22917) explains that there is a maximum of 0.92c, although realistically a speed 0.25c is more likely to be the maximum speed used.  In a situation such as the emergency in *The Schizoid Man*,  going to Gravesworld using ordinary protocols regarding warp in star systems would be an unnacceptable delay to the situation, but by using near-warp transport, it means that they do save **a considerable amount of time**, hence why they risk using it!

Comment: Why do ships drop to impulse, not drop out of warp directly by the desired planet?

Comment: Haven't we seen ships doing damage to a planet's atmosphere when using warp drives too close? I might be thinking of Battlestar Galactica

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Not that I recall - I haven't seen Battlestar Galactica though so I can't verify whether it's mentioned in that

Comment: @Pioneer I've edited my answer a bit - does this address your earlier query now?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield it wasn't damage, but just wind. There was an object, and then the object was gone, creating a vacuum. The vacuum sucked in the surrounding air, creating an implosion, and that's that. Galactica, on the other hand...